# Generating function for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^{p} x^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, summation, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I am trying to derive the generating function for $H(x,p) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^p x^n$

I am trying to solve it with the following logic:

(Edited now, trying a new framing)

Base case:

$$H(x,0) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = \dfrac{1}{1-x}$$

And

$$H(x,p) = x \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} H(x,p-1)$$

Implying

$$H(x,p) = \left(x \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)^p \dfrac{1}{1-x}$$

Comment: So, you know that $H(x, p)$ is given by applying $x \frac{d}{dx}$ $p$ times to $\frac{1}{1 - x}$. So you want to know how to do this. It's easy to apply $\frac{d}{dx}$, which helps. It turns out that you can write $\left( x \frac{d}{dx} \right)^p$ uniquely as the sum of operators of the form $x^a \left( \frac{d}{dx} \right)^b$, and the effect of these on generating functions is easy to understand. So the problem is figuring out what coefficients are involved here.

Comment: So my current approach is going nowhere, basically? I wouldn't have ever recognized this "unique sum of operators" thing. My difficulty is that I can't see the differentiation as anything other than a function acting on $H(x,p-1)$ specifically and so I don't know how to peel that out of the fact that $x$ is being multiplied by it externally... and then all of this gets nested.

Comment: @user6596353 Are you Ok with our answers? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. An approach similar to what you are looking for. One may recall the general formula

> $$
> \sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n)x^n=\frac1{1-x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\:\omega_n\left(\frac{x}{1-x} \right), \quad |x|<1, \tag1
> $$

with the polynomials $$
\omega_n\left(x \right)=\sum_{k=0}^n \begin{Bmatrix}n\\k\end{Bmatrix}k!x^k \tag2
$$ where $\displaystyle \begin{Bmatrix}n\\k\end{Bmatrix}$ are the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).
The identity $(1)$ holds true for a vast class of regular functions $f$. A proof of $(1)$ can be found in [Boyadzhiev's paper here](http://www.emis.de/journals/HOA/IJMMS/2005/233849.pdf).

Applying $(1)$ to $f(x)=x^p$, gives directly

> $$
> \sum_{n=0}^\infty n^px^n=\frac1{1-x}\:\omega_p\left(\frac{x}{1-x} \right), \quad |x|<1. \tag3
> $$

Observe that we have
$$
\left(x \frac{d}{dx} \right)^p\frac1{1-x}=\frac1{1-x}\:\omega_p\left(\frac{x}{1-x} \right).\tag4
$$

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way of describing the answer. First, the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) $S(m, k)$ have the property that

$$n^m = \sum_k S(m, k) (n)_k$$

where $(n)_k = n(n-1) \dots (n-(k-1))$. Second, the generating function of $(n)_k$ turns out to be relatively straightforward to write down: it is

$$\sum_n (n)_k x^n = k! \frac{x^k}{(1 - x)^{k+1}}.$$

You can derive this by repeatedly differentiating $\frac{1}{1 - x}$. It follows that

$$\sum_n n^m x^n = \sum_k S(m, k) k! \frac{x^k}{(1 - x)^{k+1}}.$$

This is in fact equivalent to a claim about how the differential operator $\left( x \frac{d}{dx} \right)^n$ expands, as mentioned in the comments.